# How to pass array by reference between 2 javascript files

Tags: javascript, canvas, reference

I have 2 html pages. For each of them I have 1 js file performing some code. What I want to do now is take half of the information in my canvas of the first page (lets say the left half of my canvas), and send it to my second page. In my second page I also have a canvas that shows the left half of the canvas of my previous page. The idea is that I can make modifications in this second page but I want that these modifications eventually are also visible in the canvas of the first page.

The problem I have I am not very sure how to do this. I know how to pass variables between pages. I also know how to pass the array information of the canvas using JSON to the second html page. But when I make changes to this information, the changes are not seen on my first page. I expected these changes to happen automatically because this info should be passed by reference but apparently this is not the case.

Anyone knows why these changes don't show in the first page and how to solve this issue ? Or maybe is there a better way to pass this canvas information ?

Comment: How are you passing the data between the pages currently? This sounds like a good use case for using *Storage events*.

Comment: You should look into use a SPA (Single page application) framework like Angular, Vue or React rather than using multiple html files.

Comment: look at [socket.io](https://socket.io/) and websockets. in fact there is a [whiteboard demo](https://socket.io/demos/whiteboard/)